# Ruby on Rails: how do you get the ID of an object instantly after it's been created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
media = Media.new(params[:media])

media.save

@attachment.media = Media.find(????)
@attachment.save
```

I tried just doing `media.id` but apparently, that is the media that hasn't been saved to the db yet.... so how do I get the ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `media.id` is not assigned, you probably had an error when saving and `media.save` returned `false`, though since you don't check for it you didn't notice.

The way to avoid this is to request the stricter save:

```
def something
  media = Media.new(params[:media])

  media.save!

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  # Something couldn't be saved

  render(...)
end
```

Generally if a record saves correctly, then `media.errors.full_messages` will be an empty array.

If there are no errors, then it is possible that one of your `before_` or `after_` filters returned false and prevented it from being saved, though this is less common.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do the following?

```
media = Media.new(params[:media])

media.save

@attachment.media = media
@attachment.save
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the build_xxx methods you get via the association?

```
@attachment.build_media(params[:media])
@attachment.save
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this media object is not valid, thus has not been saved.

If it would be saved, you would have media.id already set.